# Right way of setting up of Caffe deep learning framework

Tags: caffe

As part of one of my AI experiment, am trying to set up Caffe framework in windows (CPU based) system and facing issues during the set up.

System configuration:

- Windows 10 - 64 bit – CPU Only (No GPU)
- Python 3+

I was referring to the caffe website http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html for installation. 
I have taken care of the key requirements mentioned in the site and after which when I try to the run the build script (as mentioned in the installation steps), I’m getting the following error.

Can anyone please point me the right setting up of 'caffe’ deep learning framework. if you could share any inputs/ideas/suggestions are also welcome

[image: err_in_caffe]

Comment: can anyone please tell, why its downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed Cmake or Ninja as mentioned in “[System Requirements](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/windows)”?

Also it could help others to look into this if you posted the error messages as text instead of the image.